# Mysql trigger or stored procedure to update column A on update of column B in same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have created a library database and one of the table is `transaction` which is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE action
(
t_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
b_id int,
m_id int,
borrow_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
is_returned Bool Default 0,
is_lost Bool,
is_damaged Bool,
return_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
f_id int,
PRIMARY KEY (t_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_bookId FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES book(b_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_memberId FOREIGN KEY (m_id) REFERENCES member(m_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_fineId FOREIGN KEY (f_id) REFERENCES fine(f_id)
);
```

I want to update `return_timestamp` arrtibute to the timestamp which is when `is_returned` is changed to `1`

I tried this

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_return_timestamp
AFTER UPDATE
ON action FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
DECLARE return_timestamp timestamp;

   SELECT is_returned FROM action
   IF is_return IS 1
        BEGIN
           INSERT INTO transaction (return_timestamp) VALUES (now())
        END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Where am I going wrong? Or what is the correct approach? I don't know how to do this

Comment: Does this code even work? transaction is a reserved keyword http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Comment: yes it did work.. i got table created with above code

Comment: but please do consider changing to a more sensible table name. Your trigger function looks very confusing because one cannot tell whether you are referring to the transaction table or the transaction keyword in it.

Comment: I am sorry, I changed it to action. I hope that doesn't confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your `Trigger` before updating the record.
if the new update set `is_returned` field then you set `return_timestamp` field.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_return_timestamp

BEFORE UPDATE ON `action` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.is_returned = 1 Then
    Set NEW.return_timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
END IF;

END
```